# There's nothing here, yet. heroku

Tags: php, git, heroku

I have just created a new app on heroku firstsiteapp. I followed the instructions on heroku created Created a new  repo.

```
$ cd my-project/
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a firstsiteapp
```

Deployed my application

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

But when I navigate to the site firstsiteapp.heroku.com,I still get the default html page with title no such app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command "`git pull`" in your server, meant retrieve those files you had updated - "`git push`".

Comment: On Server side? if so, please confirm those files have been in Server and check the Web Service setting next, sometimes default page come from incomplete setting.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic deploys upon push need to be configured. Navigate to `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_NAME>/deploy` and enable automatic deploys for the master branch. You can also deploy manually - useful for the first deploys.

You also need to check that builds where successful: apps that fails build don't get deployed. Build status can be checked in the activity tab: `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_NAME>/activity`.